# Sort array without using temporary variables

Tags: php, sorting

I am doing a program. In that there is an array sorting function like below

```
$arr= array(10,2,13,5,8);

for($i=0; $i<count($arr)-1; $i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j<count($arr)-1; $j++)
    {
        if($arr[$j]> $arr[$j+1]){
            $temp= $arr[$j+1];
            $arr[$j+1]= $arr[$j];
            $arr[$j]= $temp;
        }
    }

}
print_r($arr);
```

Here I am using a `temp` variable to store the values temporarily.

Is there a way to do this sorting with out a `temp` variable?

**I don't want to do this with any built in PHP functions**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: @cornelb, Sorry to make you misunderstand it. I don't want to do this using any in built functions. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: You are looking for **in-place sorting algorithms**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = array(10,2,13,5,8);

for($i=0; $i<count($arr)-1; $i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j<count($arr)-1; $j++)
    {
        if($arr[$j]> $arr[$j+1]){
            list($arr[$j],$arr[$j+1]) = array($arr[$j+1], $arr[$j]); 
        }
    }

}
print_r($arr);
```

If they are integers, another way of swapping them is

```
$a = $a + $b; 
$b = $a - $b; 
$a = $a - $b;
```

Comment: That is awesome and working perfect. But I couldn't get the idea behind the line `list($arr[$j],$arr[$j+1]) = array($arr[$j+1], $arr[$j]); `. Can you please explain. Thanks a lot

Comment: Creating `array` of to elements, and then save this as split elements in destination - simply switch of two elements. Check [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the array-sort function. In my opion there is no need to write another array-sort-function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my question. I need to do this without the use of any in-built functions

Comment: Sorry Arun, didn't recognized your comment.

Comment: Then the answer is "NO". This is a classic case and you can't do this in place without an extra variable.